# Popoto.js Neo4j- How to start the Graph with a specific node

Tags: javascript, graph, neo4j, cypher

I have configured Popoto.js with my Neo4j and it works fine.
But my requirement is to start the grpah with a Node that I want. For example if I pass a node-id or a key constraint, the graph should start with that as the root node. By default graph starts with a the label that we pass to the start method.
Is there any option to do this?

I have tried using **getPredefinedConstraints**. That works. But unfortunately it filter the particular node type with the constraint, wherever it appears while traversing, which is not desirable.
I tried below, but that is not fully addressing my need. Please help.

```
"Person" :{
    "returnAttributes":["name","age"],
    "constraintAttribute" : "name",
    "getPredefinedConstraints": function (node) {
        x = ["$identifier.name =~ '(?i).*"  + nameValue + ".*'"];
        return x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an event listener when the root node is added to set a value like in the following example:

Note that you can also set the root node to "immutable" state to avoid value deselection.

```
/**
 * Listener used when root node is added
 * In this listener root node is initialized with a value
 * and set in immutable state to avoid value deselection.
 *
 * @param rootNode root node reference when graph is created.
 */
var rootNodeListener = function (rootNode) {

    // Change root node type and label with instanceData
    rootNode.value = {
        type: popoto.graph.node.NodeTypes.VALUE,
        label: "Person",
        attributes: {name:'Tom Hanks'}
    };

    // Set node as immutable, in this state the value cannot be deselected.
    rootNode.immutable = true;
};

// Add rootNodeListener on NODE_ROOT_ADD event
popoto.graph.on(popoto.graph.Events.NODE_ROOT_ADD, rootNodeListener);
```

See the live example here:
http://www.popotojs.com/live/simple-graph/selected-with-event.html

Or since 1.1.2 you can start Popoto with a predefined graph (including selected values) as parameter of the start function like this:

```
popoto.start({
    label: "Person",
    rel: [
        {
            label: "ACTED_IN",
            node: {
                label: "Movie",
                value: {
                    title: "The Matrix"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            label: "DIRECTED",
            node: {
                label: "Movie"
            }
        },
        {
            label: "PRODUCED",
            node: {
                label: "Movie"
            }
        },
        {
            label: "WROTE",
            node: {
                label: "Movie"
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Live example here: http://www.popotojs.com/live/results/predefined-data.html

And a more complex one here: http://www.popotojs.com/live/save/index.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
I was able to resolve this case using saved graph option, as you mentioned in example 2. But option 1 looks more ideal for my scenario, let me give a try. Especially option to make the node immutable is gonna help a lot.

Comment: How can I specify a Node ID here to start from node id?